# Click textbox to show popup, click outside to close popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am designing a WPF usercontrol, and there is a textbox and a popup under the textbox. I want to click the textbox, then the popup shows. If I click outside of the textbox, the popup closes.

Now the problem is how to unfocus the textbox if I click outside the usercontrol area? Is any better way to design this control? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On click inside you should show your popup, and to close it ater click on non-user are try to use solutions from link [Is there an event handler that is fired when mouse is clicked  outside textbox in c# Windows Form application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201864/is-there-an-event-handler-that-is-fired-when-mouse-is-clicked-outside-textbox-i)